# How do I partition in hive by a specific column?

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have 3 columns: user, datetime, and data

My data is space delimited and each row is delimited by a new line

right now I'm using the regexserde to read in my input, however I want to partition by the user. If I do that user can no longer be a column, correct? If so how do I load my data onto my tables?

Comment: How many users are you planning to have? Having tons of really small partitions would impede perfromance.

Answer (score 0):

In Hive each partition corresponds to a folder in HDFS. You can reload the data from your unpartitioned Hive table into a new partitioned HIve table using a create-table-as-select (CTAS) statement. See https://cwiki.apache.org/Hive/languagemanual-ddl.html#LanguageManualDDL-CreateTable for more details.

Comment: I wanted to avoid this since I have a lot of data.

Comment: You might need to rethink your partitioning strategy then. You would want to partition your data to facilitate partition pruning. If your table is not partitioned, the MapReduce job(s) generated by Hive would read your entire data. If you save 50% time on 2 runs of a query, you will have enough time savings to "pay" for a CTAS.

Answer (score 0):

You can order the data in HDFS in sub-directories under the current directory, the directory name has to be in the format `PART_NAME=PART_VALUE`.
If your data is split into files where in each file you have only one type of "user" just create directories corresponding to the usernames (e.g. `USERNAME=XYZ`) and put all the files that match that username in its directory.
Next you can create an external-table with partitions (see [example](http://blog.zhengdong.me/2012/02/22/hive-external-table-with-partitions)).
The only problem is that you'll have to define the column "user" that's in your data anyway (but you can just ignore it) and query the other column (`USERNAME`) which will provide the needed partition pruning.